# Prevent Build Explorer from showing

Tags: visual-studio-2013, team-foundation-server

Whenever I queue a new TFS build from VS 2013, it opens the Build Explorer window.  Is there a way to turn this off?  I prefer using the sidebar to see my builds.

Comment: Which Visual Studio 2013 Update are you using?

Comment: Any of them.  This has always happened since I started using TFS for builds.

Comment: I had a chance to try it, but Visual Studio doesn't open the Build Explorer window for me. Are you saying that, in the Team Explorer window, you right-click on a build definition -> Queue New Build... -> Queue and then the Build Explorer window for tha build gets opened?

Comment: Every time.  It's always done this, even in past versions.